# 4-pin quartz resonators - shall the 2 ground pins be connected to ground plane of the pcb?

Tags: pcb-design, crystal

I am about to use a 8MHz quartz resonator that has 4 pins (http://datasheet.octopart.com/LF-XTAL026380.-IQD-Frequency-Products-datasheet-6993.pdf):
pin 1 and 3 are connected to resonator while pins 2 and 4 are grounded (I checked that they are shorted to a metal casing).

Shall I connect pins 2 and 4 to ground plane of my pcb or leave them not connected?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to connect pins 2 and 4 to the ground plane of the PCB. It is better to add a ground fill around the device and add guard traces also so that the clock frequency generated gets better immunity from noise.

However, you should also check the clock layout considerations of your target device to see if there are any more constraints which you need to take care of.

For starters, you can refer to this link (http://www.atmel.in/Images/doc8128.pdf) which tells about the general clock layout considerations.